# Add validation group to textbox when dropdown change to specific value

Tags: c#, validation, onchange

I have a form with textbox, radiobutton etc. and would like to have a validationgroup attached to some of the input fields when one dropdown changes to a specific value. Is that possible.

lets say i have this form;

```
<form>
Name:
      <asp:textbox runat="server" id="nametextbox" ValidationGroup="myvalgroup"/>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="nametextboxFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name?" ValidationGroup="myvalgroup" ControlToValidate="nametextbox" />

Gender: <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="gender" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ValidationGroup="myvalgroup">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select gender" Value="" Selected="True"/>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="Male"/>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="Female"/>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="genderFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Gender?" ValidationGroup="myvalgroup" ControlToValidate="gender" />

The answer to life the universe and everything:
        <asp:textbox runat="server" id="theanswer" />

Are you finished?
      <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="finished" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onchange="add-validation-group()" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Are you done?" Value="" Selected="True"/>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"/>
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"/>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Absolutly not, i need 600 more years to think!" Value="NOT-IN-600-YEARS"/>
      </asp:RadioButtonList>

      <asp:button runat="server" id="submitbutton" />
</form>
```

Codebehind

```
function add-validation-group()
    if (finished.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Yes")
        {
            theanswer.Attributes.Add("ValidationGroup", "myvalgroup"); 
        }
end
```

Ok so my codebehind contains a mixup of everything but just to show what i would like to acomplish, sorry for the codemixing!

So can this be done, add validation to inputfields when onchange on a dropdownlist?

Point me in the right direction, please! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution to my question.
Quite simple i might add.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= finished.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            if ($('option:selected', this).text() == 'Yes') {
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=theanswerValidator.ClientID%>'), true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
Name:
  <asp:textbox runat="server" id="nametextbox" ValidationGroup="myvalgroup"/>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="nametextboxFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name?" ValidationGroup="myvalgroup" ControlToValidate="nametextbox" />

Gender: <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="gender" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ValidationGroup="myvalgroup">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select gender" Value="" Selected="True"/>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="Male"/>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="Female"/>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="genderFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Gender?" ValidationGroup="myvalgroup" ControlToValidate="gender" />

The answer to life the universe and everything:
    <asp:textbox runat="server" id="theanswer" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="theanswerValidator" Enabled="false" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Your answer?" ValidationGroup="myvalgroup" ControlToValidate="theanswer" />

Are you finished?
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="finished" >
        <asp:ListItem Text="Are you done?" Value="" Selected="True"/>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"/>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"/>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Absolutly not, i need 600 more years to think!" Value="NOT-IN-600-YEARS"/>
  </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:button runat="server" id="submitbutton" />
</form>
```

I added required field validators to theanswer textbox and added Enabled="false" i then track a onchange event with javascript to see if user selects Yes and if they do enable the requiredfieldvalidator.

In my question i had a Radiobuttonlist for the (are you finished?), But changed that to a DropdownList instead for other reasons but i cant think that this is impossible if you have radiobutton list.

OK, it's not in codebehind but it works.
I did try to do it codebehind but it dident feel user friendly to have a Postback on select change.

If someone is intrested in the codebehind method i did it this way, and it worked but (in my opinion not so user friendly)

On my asp:Dropdownlist i added

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="finished_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
```

and in my codebehind i added this:

```
protected void finished_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

   if (ddl.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Yes"))
   {
      theanswerValidator.Enabled = true;
   }
   else  // If someone selects yes and then regret it and selects no then disable validator again
   {
      theanswerValidator.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```